# Pass value between components - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a react-native app where i ask questions about an on going survey and i render each question in a form custom made card component:

```
const { cardTitle, cardDescription, onYesPress, onNoPress } = this.props;
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card containerStyle={styles.votingCardContainer} title={cardTitle}>
          <View style={styles.votingCard}>
            <Text style={{ alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 23 }}>
              {cardDescription}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <CustomIconButton
                  onPress={onYesPress}
                  iconName={icons.YES}
                  iconColor={'green'}
                  iconSize={70}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <CustomIconButton
                  onPress={onNoPress}
                  iconName={icons.NO}
                  iconColor={'red'}
                  iconSize={70}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
```

when users login, i got survey questions from DB and render them in the form of  `OnGoingSurvey` component in `MainScreen` component.

```
          <OnGoingSurveyCard
            onYesPress={this.handleYesPress}
            onNoPress={this.handleNoPress}
            cardTitle={"Question Title "}
            cardDescription={"Question Description?"}
          />
```

As you can see  `OnGoingSurvey` has two buttons, Yes and No. I need to know which question is answered by user and what is his/her answer. But i dont know how to pass survey and answer data between  `OnGoingSurvey` and `MainScreen` component and post this data to DB again.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

First of all, thank you for your answer. I did everything you said and it works like a charm except one thing but i am sure it is caused by me. I create a scenario where when a user pressed an answer,

```
  handleAnswerPress = (yesPressed, questionId) => {
    if (yesPressed) {
      this.setState({
        surveyAnswer: 'Yes',
        whichSurvey: questionId,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        surveyAnswer: 'No',
        whichSurvey: questionId,
      });
    }
    console.warn(this.state.whichSurvey, this.state.surveyAnswer);
  };
```

where `questionId` and `questionAnswer` were set null initially.

```
   this.state = {
      whichSurvey: null,
      surveyAnswer: null,
    };
  }
```

when i pressed one of those buttons the first press warn `questionId` : `null` `questionAnswer` : `null` , and the second output is the one where i pressed before. for example if i pressed yes and then no, it first shows null null and then `questionId`  and `no`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the question `id` to the `OnGoingSurveyCard`

```
          <OnGoingSurveyCard
            id={1}
            onYesPress={this.handleYesPress}
            onNoPress={this.handleNoPress}
            cardTitle={"Question Title "}
            cardDescription={"Question Description?"}
          />
```

Then pass id when user click any of the button

```
const { id, cardTitle, cardDescription, onYesPress, onNoPress } = this.props;
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card containerStyle={styles.votingCardContainer} title={cardTitle}>
          <View style={styles.votingCard}>
            <Text style={{ alignItems: 'center', fontSize: 23 }}>
              {cardDescription}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <CustomIconButton
                  onPress={(e) => onYesPress(id)}
                  iconName={icons.YES}
                  iconColor={'green'}
                  iconSize={70}
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <CustomIconButton
                  onPress={(e) => onNoPress(id)}
                  iconName={icons.NO}
                  iconColor={'red'}
                  iconSize={70}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
```

Then in `handleYessPress` and `handleNoPress` you can get it like this:

```
handleYesPress = id => {
    //id is the id of question
}
```

I would also suggest you to use only one function if they are kind of the same (it seems like so):

```
handlePress = (yesPressed, questionId) => {
      this.setState({
        surveyAnswer: yesPressed ? "Yes" : "No",
        whichSurvey: questionId,
      });
}

<OnGoingSurveyCard
  id={1}
  handlePress={this.handlePress}
  cardTitle={"Question Title "}
  cardDescription={"Question Description?"}
/>

//YES BUTTON
<CustomIconButton
    onPress={(e) => handlePress(true, id)}
    iconName={icons.YES}
    iconColor={'green'}
    iconSize={70}
/>

//NO BUTTON
<CustomIconButton
    onPress={(e) => handlePress(false, id)}
    iconName={icons.NO}
    iconColor={'red'}
    iconSize={70}
/>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I did everything you said and it works like a charm except one thing but i am sure it is caused by me. 
I create a scenario where when a user pressed an answer, i ```console.warn(questionId, questionAnswer)```
where ```questionId``` and ```questionAnswer``` were set null initially. when i pressed one of those buttons 

the first press warn is null null, and the second output is the one where i pressed before. for example if i pressed yes and then no, it first shows null null and then ```questionId``` and ```no```

Comment: @AlkanV can you update your question, and add the current code so I take a look at it?

Comment: @AlkanV the problem about that i guess is that the `setState` works `asynchronous`. So instead try to `console.log(yesPressed, questionId)` and check the value.

Comment: @AlkanV also check my updated answer so you dont need to write `if/else` statement in `handlePress()` method

Comment: thank you for your interest. Everything works perfect thanks to you.

Comment: @AlkanV make sure to mark it as the best answer, so other could use it!